# Java System.out.println takes so much time when called from PHP using exec()

Tags: java, php, eclipse, performance, lucene

I am building a web-application with PHP front-end and Java as a back-end to retrieve information from the customized Lucene index.

On the PHP, I use exec() to run the JAR that retrieve results from Java lucene index (that prints out only metdata results of the documents and we are dealing with about 300+ lines of String or results). I figured the more the results, the slower the speed of search from PHP. It took roughly 4-5 secs to retrieve 300 line of results but in Java(using Eclipse IDE), only 0.3 sec or lesser is required to retrieve the same results using the same method. I tried running JAR directly from command-line and the search speed is in the middle

So I put timer in the Java to debug the problem and found that what seems to be slowing down is the use of System.out.println(). Without printing out the search results, the search speed in PHP is as fast as in Java IDE.

Is there a good way to capture the output of Java methods from PHP without compromising the speed? I want my search engine to be scale-able and handle more results. btw, I am developing on Windows 7.

Comment: I'd check [PHP/Java Bridge](http://php-java-bridge.sourceforge.net/pjb/). Pull up VM for each PHP request can be pretty expansive (in terms of time and resources).

Comment: Last update of that project is 2013, doesn't seem like that good advice. Also way too few people have downloaded that, doesnt seem to have benchmarks, etc.

Comment: @AdrianoRepetti. I have tried 'Invoke Java desktop application methods.' from PHP/Java Bridge. It does not return object or output back to PHP.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a very broad subject that involves architecture design and many other things. But to summarize a useful answer I would advice you abandon the current "exec a jar" approach, and convert your java backend into a tomcat webapp, that is always running in the background, ready to answer and without the need to warm up again everytime.

Also, this enables you to cache results, and to scale horizontally (adding another tomcat on the side and balancing charge), etc.

More importantly, you would be using streaming, which is what tomcat would be using via its httpResponse object, which should have considerably better performance than system.out, and last but not least, exec creates a new process at the operating system level, but tomcat use threads (simplifying and for your scenario, should mean better performance).

I would give all that a try, and also google some "apache lucene php client" and see what comes out.

EDIT: have a look at Apache SolR: http://lucene.apache.org/solr/features.html

Is a standalone server powered by Lucene that already features a REST-like API. This will save you the trouble of making a tomcat webapp of your own.

EDIT 2: there is a PHP SolR Client: https://github.com/PTCInc/solr-php-client, but I haven't tried it myself.

Comment: "Why is <simple thing X> slow?" "Oh, because you should rewrite your entire application using <complicated thing Y>."

Comment: It's a valid and fundamented opinion. I'm telling you, this "simple" thing won't scale, there are A LOT of things that WILL go wrong if you execute a jar with every web request. I'm sorry you don't see it but the entire approach is wrong and this performance issues are just a sympthom. Also, read the downvote privilege page again, "downvote is not a substitute for editing and communication". If you find my answer too complex or whatever just leave t there.

Comment: @jotadepicas, thanks for the suggestion. You are right about exec creating a new child process instead of a thread. I have come across the article in lucene tutorial where it suggested to use 'Use a Java Lucene backend which interacts with your front-end using HTTP or SOAP'. but It does not elaborate much on it. Is it the same as Tomcat webapp technique? TY !

Comment: @jotadepicas However, the question was not "How can I write a Java web app that can still work at large scales?", it was "Why is this slow even at a small scale?"

Comment: @KyleK yes, precisely, one of the more common ways to build this "backend" they mention is to do it as a java webapp deployed in a tomcat server (or another server like jetty, etc). The key here is that you should get much better results if you interact with a process that is always running (like a webapp) and stream results via http (using XML or JSON). However don't think about this as a major refactor on your PHP code. You should be able, more or less, to migrate you jar code inside a java servlet to begin, and replece de PHP exec by a PHP http invocation to this new backend.

Comment: @immibis he literally says he wants his search engine to be scalable. Executing a jar every time will not achieve that by far and in my opinion, it is better to question the general approach than hack our way out of this particular issue.

Comment: @KyleK I made the mistake of not mentioning Apache SolR before, sorry about that: http://lucene.apache.org/solr/features.html
SolR is built upon lucene, and is a standalone server that already has a REST API :) I'll update my answer with this. I've worked with SolR and is pretty powerful.

Comment: @jotadepicas I have looked into Solr before. The requirement of my work is not to index the whole document so not sure Solr could be helpful. I think i'll try web app for now. About this streaming thing, I am not sure about how to implement that. What I am thinking is using PHP "file_get_contents" to retrieve the results from Java web app address.(localhost:8080/javaFunction).

Answer (score 0):

Alright! the speed issue is gone. Here's how is solved it:

I deployed a java-backend web app (suggested by @jotadepicas)on a Tomcat server from Eclipse IDE and capture the output from PHP with file_get_contents() function. For now, I just need to learn how to setup webapp on tomcat on XAMPP instead of Eclipse IDE.

Thank you all for helping me solve this. huge thanks to @jotadepicas !

Comment: Hey! Glad you made it work. If you feel like it accept my answer. About deploying tomcat outside eclipse it shouldn't be difficult. Google how to generare a .war file with your webapp, drop that into webapps folder in tomcat and that is pretty much it. If you nedd/want, google for more sophisticated ways to do that like a Maven build.

Comment: Also have a look at this as an alternative if file_get_contents: http://php.net/manual/en/httprequest.send.php

Comment: Sorry, first time using stackoverflow and not aware of how to set it as an answer. I was trying to upvote but don't have enough rep. Thanks for the further. really appreciate it !.